# Where would deliverables such as wireframes/interview schedules/heuristic evaluations/contextual enquires etc come under

Tags: website-design, portfolio

I am in the process of redesigning my portfolio and I was planning to use create a portfolio with a filter, like [this example](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/portfolio).

Though my initial plan was to have just two major categories, namely user experience projects and website design, I've realized that I could include other stuff relevant to my UX experience, as such as heuristic evaluation reports, Fitts's law evaluations, contextual enquiries, stand-alone wireframes, and prototypes.

Now, the question is what category would these fall into since they are technically not projects on their own but rather small deliverables, which were completed independently.

This might not be a strictly UX question as such but I can't think of a better forum to ask since I am pretty sure this is a challenge a lot of designers might face while designing their portfolio.

Comment: Why can't they fall under the *UX* section?

Comment: My challenge here is  I was planning to keep full end to end projects in the UX project section but these are like more stand alone deliverable s (though in larger projects,they would be part of the process)

Comment: I don't think the distinction is important. A portfolio is 'Stuff I've done' and whether it was a large or small project, parts or a whole, people are really just interested in the work you produce. I wouldn't overthink this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered a faceted approach?

If you examine the [example portfolio you linked to](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/portfolio) you might notice that some of their projects appear under more than one category. Rhodes Scholarship for example is under both Non-Profit and also Education.

Similarly you could have top level categories of UX Projects, Design Projects, and Methods. (Within UX Projects and Design Projects you might have some broad industry groupings like the linked example).

Importantly, under Methods you could have a list of the different techniques you've used across all projects and your site visitor could then select a method and see all projects that involved that technique. You could include under this hierarchy the non-project portfolio pieces right alongside links to the project portfolio pieces which feature those methods.